# I want to add 'image load button' to my opencv project

Tags: python, opencv

I make a simple OpenCV painting program. (for create MASK)

In bellow program, the image's path is written in the sourcecode. (hard coding)

but, I want to load an image by a button.

How can I make a button on this program?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


win_name ='Image Recovery'
image_path='earth.jpg'

penThick=10


def onChange(value):
    global penThick
    penThick = cv.getTrackbarPos('penThick', win_name)

    print(penThick)

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global srcImage, maskLayer, paintingImage
    #paintingImage = param[0]
    #maskLayer = param[1]

    if event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE :
        if flags & cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN :
            cv.circle(maskLayer, (x,y), penThick, (0, 0, 0), -1);
            cv.circle(paintingImage, (x, y), penThick, (0, 0, 0), -1);

    if event == cv.EVENT_RBUTTONDBLCLK :
        maskLayer = (255,255,255)
        paintingImage = cv.imread(image_path, cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)

    cv.imshow(win_name, paintingImage)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global srcImage, maskLayer, paintingImage
    srcImage = cv.imread(image_path, cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
    paintingImage = cv.imread(image_path, cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)

    maskLayer = np.zeros((srcImage.shape[0], srcImage.shape[1] , 3), np.uint8)
    maskLayer[:] = (255,255,255)

    cv.namedWindow(win_name, cv.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED)
    cv.imshow(win_name, paintingImage)
    cv.setMouseCallback(win_name,mouse_callback, (paintingImage, maskLayer))
    cv.createTrackbar('penThick',win_name, 10, 15, onChange)

    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.imwrite("out.png", maskLayer)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can’t tell what you are using as the GUI.

The most approachable GUI comes in pythons standard library. It looks a little out of place but it does the job.

You can try fitting the code below in your program.

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialogue


gui_root = Tk()
image_path = filedialogue.askopenfilename(initialdir=“/“, title=“Pick an Image”, filetypes=((“Image Files”, “*.jpg”),(“All Files”, “*.*”)
```